# Correct use of groups in Doxygen?

Tags: doxygen

I'm trying create a document with the structure:

```
+ Header
+-+ A
+-+ B
+-+ C
```

My source code is:

```
/**

\defgroup bigsection Header
@{


\defgroup sectionA A
@{
A 
@}

\defgroup sectionB B
@{
B
@}


\defgroup sectionC C
@{
C
@}


@}

*/
```

What I end up with is the following structure:

```
+ Header
+-+ A
+-+ B
+ C
```

Does anyone know why?

Comment: I see this behavior with version 1.6.3 (released early 2010), but not with any newer version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like this was a bug in Doxygen. Is resolved in later versions.